# Flutter build Expansion tiles from List

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I know how to build Expansion tiles Statically, but am having trouble figuring out how to create them from a List. Could anyone help with this?

The Expansion tiles, would have up to three levels.

For example here is the 3 level list:

```
final List<MenuItem> loadedItems = [
MenuItem(
  id: "1",
  title: "MEN",
  type: "I",
  menuItems: [
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Clothing",
      type: "I",
      menuItems: [
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Tees & Tanks",
          type: "B",
        ),
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Shirts & Polos",
          type: "B",
        ),
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Boardshorts",
          type: "B",
        ),
      ],
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Accessories",
      type: "I",
      menuItems: [
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Caps & Hats & Beanies",
          type: "B",
        ),
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Wallets",
          type: "B",
        ),
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Socks",
          type: "B",
        ),
      ],
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Watches",
      type: "B",
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Footwear",
      type: "B",
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Sunglasses",
      type: "B",
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Special Offers",
      type: "B",
    ),
  ],
),
```

Been scratching my head for some time over this one, so would really appreciate any help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[].map((e){}).toList();` to iterate through a list and return list of widgets.

Here's the code

```
class ExpansionTileDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpansionTileDemoState createState() => _ExpansionTileDemoState();
}

class _ExpansionTileDemoState extends State<ExpansionTileDemo> {


final List<MenuItem> loadedItems = [
MenuItem(
  id: "1",
  title: "MEN",
  type: "I",
  menuItems: [
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Clothing",
      type: "I",
      menuItems: [
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Tees & Tanks",
          type: "B",
        ),
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Shirts & Polos",
          type: "B",
        ),
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Boardshorts",
          type: "B",
        ),
      ],
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Accessories",
      type: "I",
      menuItems: [
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Caps & Hats & Beanies",
          type: "B",
        ),
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Wallets",
          type: "B",
        ),
        MenuItem(
          id: "1",
          title: "Socks",
          type: "B",
        ),
      ],
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Watches",
      type: "B",
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Footwear",
      type: "B",
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Sunglasses",
      type: "B",
    ),
    MenuItem(
      id: "1",
      title: "Special Offers",
      type: "B",
    ),
  ],
),



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Expansion Tile Demo'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: monthModel.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _buildList(loadedItems[index]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(MenuItem item) {
    return Card(
      child: ExpansionTile(
        title: Text(
          item.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        children: items
                .map((e){
                return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              e.title,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            ),
          ) 
             }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the example. However please note that for some of the elements there are three levels of menu items to open. Where as the code above only opens two levels. I've tried to adapt it but have been unable. So for example, with MEN / CLOTHING / TEES & TANKS the result should be: EXPANSIONTILE / EXPANSIONTILE / LISTTILE. Many thanks